CRTP: Type conversion error calling base function from derived class
I'm new to CRTP and heavily templated code so I'm not sure if this is possible...
I have a template class as follows:
template<typename ...T>
class base_type_components
{
public:
    template<std::size_t i>
    std::tuple_element_t<i, std::tuple<T...>>
    component()
    {
        return std::get<i>(_components);
    }

    constexpr std::size_t
    num_components() const
    {
        return sizeof...(T);
    }
private:
    std::tuple<T...> _components;
};

This parent class takes a list of types and generates a tuple for 'component storage'.
I can access these components by calling x.component<0>(), &c. However my child class is also a template, so I actually use this->template component<0>() internally.
My child class is defined as so:
template<std::size_t L = 199>
class type_derived_st :
    public base_type_components<std::string>
{
public:
    std::string
    value() const
    {
        return this->template component<0>();
    }

    ...
};

This class is also a template. The template arg L is used elsewhere in other code unrelated to the problem.
The problem lies in the return statement for type_derived_st<L>::value.
When I instantiate the class as type_derived_st<5> and try to run the value function, I get the following compile-time error:

error: cannot convert 'const type_derived_st<5>*' to 'base_type_components<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >*'

I don't understand what is preventing conversion here?
If I do the following:
type_derived_st<5> x;
std::string s = x.component<0>();

Then it works perfectly. It's only when I try to call the function internally to the template derived class that this error occurs:
type_derived_st<5> x;
std::string s = x.value(); // error!

MRE:
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

template<typename ...T>
class base_type_components
{
public:
    template<std::size_t i>
    std::tuple_element_t<i, std::tuple<T...>>
    component()
    {
        return std::get<i>(_components);
    }

    constexpr std::size_t
    num_components() const
    {
        return sizeof...(T);
    }
private:
    std::tuple<T...> _components;
};

template<std::size_t L = 199>
class type_derived_st :
    public base_type_components<std::string>
{
public:
    type_derived_st() = default;
    ~type_derived_st() = default;

    std::string
    value() const
    {
        return this->template component<0>();
    }
};

int
main()
{
    type_derived_st<5> x;
    std::string y = x.value();

    return 0;
}


Can you post a [mre] in a single code block w/ all required #include and w/o syntax errors, namely missing semicolons? It will attract more willing to help you. Now it takes too much efforts for getting your code compiled. I've tried that https://godbolt.org/z/Pc9c9vhWv. You said it works perfectly, but it does not. So, a complete example should be posted.

@3CxEZiVlQ Done. It works perfectly when calling component directly from a concrete implementation of the template only. I've added an MRE which shows the error I'm getting. PS: There were some typos cleaning it up but we're good now.

In fact I'm not even sure this is CRTP any more given I've trimmed it down.

value() is const but component() is non-const. Simple as that. All the template stuff is a red herring.

@IgorTandetnik Indeed... Guess I'll be using const_cast in some functions. Thank you.

First, this is not a case of CRTP. In CRTP, the derived class would be in the template parameter to the base class:
template<class T>
class base {};

class derived : public base<derived> {};

Now, the real problem is that you are trying to call the non-const qualified function component<0>() from the const qualified function value(). You need to make component<0>() const qualified too. If you actually want the user of the class to be able to modify the component at i, provide two overloads and return the value by reference:
template <typename... T>
class base_type_components {
public:
    template <std::size_t I>
    auto const& component() const {       // this will be used by value()
//       ^^^^^^             ^^^^^
        return std::get<I>(_components);
    }
    template <std::size_t I>
    auto& component() {                   // here component I is mutable
//      ^
        return std::get<I>(_components);
    }

private:
    std::tuple<T...> _components;
};

You also don't need this->template. Just call the function normally and return a const& instead of returning the string by-value. If the caller wants to copy it, they will, otherwise a copy is unnecessary:
template <std::size_t L = 199>
class type_derived_st : public base_type_components<std::string> {
public:
    type_derived_st() = default;
    ~type_derived_st() = default;

    std::string const& value() const { return component<0>(); }
//              ^^^^^^                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
};

